# In Wordpress, get_post_meta(); doesn't work in Learnpress course page in Learnpress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, function, plugins, custom-wordpress-pages

I am using Wordpress Learnpress plugin. I want to show some custom fields. So, add_meta_box(); the output that's mean save and update is okay. But, doesn't show in the front end view of single course page template.

**N.B:** In post single.php, the output is okay. 
Please see the following code:

**function.php:**

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'add_my_tab1' );
function add_my_tab1(){
    $screens = ['post', 'lp_course'];
    add_meta_box('fav_tab1_title', 'Tab 1 Title', 'fav_tab1_title', $screens);
}

function fav_tab1_title(){
    global $post;
    $get_all_meta_values = get_post_custom($post->ID);
    $fav_tab1_title = $get_all_meta_values["fav_tab1_title"][0];
    echo '<div><label style="width:130px;display:block;">Tab 1 Title:</label>
    <input type="text" name="fav_tab1_title" size="100" value="'.$fav_tab1_title.'" /></div>';
}

add_action('save_post', 'save_fav_tab1_title_title');
function save_fav_tab1_title_title(){
    global $post;
    update_post_meta($post->ID, "fav_tab1_title", $_POST["fav_tab1_title"]);   
}
?>
```

**In single course:**

```
echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'fav_tab1_title', true);?>
```

But the output is null. Please help me...

Answer (score 0):

use `get_field` function instead of `get_post_meta`
so the code would be like this:

```
echo get_field( get_the_ID(), 'fav_tab1_title', true);?>
```

Comment: That's the wrong order of parameters, the function signature is `get_field($selector, [$post_id], [$format_value]);` - so it needs to be `get_field('fav_tab1_title', get_the_ID(), true)`